# R reshape wide to long data

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape

I have a dataframe like so:

```
 [1] "drugevent"    "prr"          "prr_lowerCI"  "prr_upperCI"  "EBGM"        
[6] "EBG_lowerCI"  "EBGM_upperCI" "strata.coded" "strata"       "Reference"
```

And I want to make a plot for each drugevent, using ggplot. In order to do so I need to format my DF like so:

```
[1] "drug", "event", "measurement"(prr or EBGM), "lowerCI"(for coresponding measurement), upperCI, strata
```

But despite the many posts on SO, or R tutorials I was not able to corectly reshape the data. In my last try I added an Id like so:

```
mutate(DF, count=1:n())
```

melted the data

```
melt(DF, id.vars="count")
```

then I made several DFs subsetting the values of interest

```
subset(melted, variable in c("prr","EBGM"))
```

then the upper and lower confidence intervals, strata and drug event,
but when I merged them like so:

```
merge(measurement, lowerCI, by="count")
```

in the end I had duplicated values with 4 rows for each count.
The code is messy and the result is wrong. Could you please help me with this?

Edit exampples:
initial data:

```
drugevent       prr prr_lowerCI prr_upperCI
1 CLARITHROMYCIN-Erythema Multiforme 1.3539930   0.1903270    2.517659
2 CLARITHROMYCIN-Erythema Multiforme 1.7741342   0.6647390    2.883529
 EBGM EBG_lowerCI EBGM_upperCI      strata count
1 0.9003325   0.2128934     2.772558     Infants     1
2 1.4471096   0.5997188     3.053965    Children     2
```

the desired result:

```
    measurement     value     upperCI  strata   drug
1           prr 1.353992979  2.51765895 Infants CLARITHROMYCIN
2          EBGM  0.9009       2.77      Infants CLARITHROMYCIN
 reaction              lowerCI
1 Erythema Multiforme  2.51765895
2 Erythema Multiforme  1.447
```

Comment: please include a minimal test data frame and the expected transform

Comment: The first element is not even a `data.frame`, it's a vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you want a long format of the original data frame split based on prr or ebgm

```
dfPRR <- cbind(df[, !grepl("EBG", colnames(df))], measurement="prr")
colnames(dfPRR)[2:4] <- c("value", "lowerCI", "upperCI")
dfEBGM <- cbind(df[, !grepl("prr", colnames(df))], measurement="EBGM")
colnames(dfEBGM)[2:4] <- c("value", "lowerCI", "upperCI")
rbind(dfPRR, dfEBGM)
```

Data used

```
structure(list(drugevent = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "CLARITHROMYCIN-Erythema Multiforme", class = "factor"), 
prr = c(1.353993, 1.7741342), prr_lowerCI = c(0.190327, 0.664739
), prr_upperCI = c(2.517659, 2.883529), EBGM = c(0.9003325, 
1.4471096), EBG_lowerCI = c(0.2128934, 0.5997188), EBGM_upperCI = c(2.772558, 
3.053965), strata = structure(1:2, .Label = c("     Infants", 
"    Children"), class = "factor"), count = 1:2), .Names = c("drugevent", 
"prr", "prr_lowerCI", "prr_upperCI", "EBGM", "EBG_lowerCI", "EBGM_upperCI", 
"strata", "count"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L
))
```

Comment: thank you very much sir! I've been struggling  with this for days and wrote code that would scare even toyota, using tidyr, dplyr, reshape at once. Thanks!